# No menu in openbox

Tags: linux, arch-linux, openbox

Right clicking on the desktop yields no menu.

I tried deleting my menu.xml file and regenerating it, nothing.
I tried running openbox --debug, and nothing obvious.

What else can I try?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a binding for right-click in rc.xml (http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Bindings).  If you try binding a key to bring up the menu, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to bind the "right-click" in ./config/openbox/rc.xml

You have to lookin for Menus.

This is an example.

```
  <mousebind button="Right" action="Press">
    <action name="ShowMenu">
      <menu>root-menu</menu>
    </action>
  </mousebind>
```

I hope your problem is about this.

Answer (score -1):

Having the same problem and found a workaround.Forgot where I found the answer, will search for it and post here.

This will enable you to use Alt+F1 to open the root-menu but button click problem remains.

Assuming you have the following files in ~/.config/openbox

```
autostart  environment  menu.xml  rc.xml
```

Add the following lines to rc.xml

```
181     <keybind key="A-F1">
182       <action name="ShowMenu">
183         <menu>root-menu</menu>
184       </action>
185     </keybind>
```

Then add the following line to the autostart file

```
ksuperkey -e 'Super_L=Alt_L|F1' &
```